# How to synchronize server to client database using sql

Tags: c#, sql, database, synchronization

I am working on project where i need to use database synchronization for offline apps.
Up to some extent i am successful, i am done with synchronization for client to server using code below

```
 DbServerSyncProvider serverSyncProvider = new DbServerSyncProvider();

            SyncAgent syncAgent = new SyncAgent();               
            syncAgent.RemoteProvider = serverSyncProvider;


            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            //
            // 2. Prepare server db connection and attach it to the sync agent
            //
            builder["Data Source"] = textServerMachine.Text;
            builder["integrated Security"] = true;
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = "pub";
            SqlConnection serverConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

            serverSyncProvider.Connection = serverConnection;


            //
            // 3. Prepare client db connection and attach it to the sync provider
            //                                
            string connString = "Data Source=" + dbPathTextBox.Text;

            if (false == File.Exists(dbPathTextBox.Text))
            {                 
                SqlCeEngine clientEngine = new SqlCeEngine(connString);
                clientEngine.CreateDatabase();
                clientEngine.Dispose();
            }                
            SqlCeClientSyncProvider clientSyncProvider = new SqlCeClientSyncProvider(connString);
            syncAgent.LocalProvider = clientSyncProvider;


            //
            // 4. Create SyncTables and SyncGroups
            // To sync a table, a SyncTable object needs to be created and setup with desired properties:
            // TableCreationOption tells the agent how to initialize the new table in the local database
            // SyncDirection is how changes from with respect to client {Download, Upload, Bidirectional or Snapshot}
            //
            //
            SyncTable tableOrders = new SyncTable("orders");
            tableOrders.CreationOption = TableCreationOption.DropExistingOrCreateNewTable;
            tableOrders.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.Bidirectional;

            SyncTable tableOrderDetails = new SyncTable("order_details");
            tableOrderDetails.CreationOption = TableCreationOption.DropExistingOrCreateNewTable;
            tableOrderDetails.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.Bidirectional;

            //
            // Sync changes for both tables as one bunch, using SyncGroup object
            // This is important if the tables has PK-FK relationship, grouping will ensure that 
            // and FK change won't be applied before its PK is applied
            //
            //
            SyncGroup orderGroup = new SyncGroup("AllChanges");
            tableOrders.SyncGroup = orderGroup;
            tableOrderDetails.SyncGroup = orderGroup;

            syncAgent.Configuration.SyncTables.Add(tableOrders);
            syncAgent.Configuration.SyncTables.Add(tableOrderDetails);



            //
            // 5. Create sync adapter for each sync table and attach it to the server provider
            // Following DataAdapter style in ADO.NET, SyncAdapte is the equivelent for
            // Sync. SyncAdapterBuilder is a helper class to simplify the process of 
            // creating sync commands.                 
            //
            //

            SqlSyncAdapterBuilder ordersBuilder = new SqlSyncAdapterBuilder();                
            ordersBuilder.Connection = serverConnection;
            ordersBuilder.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.Bidirectional;

            // base table
            ordersBuilder.TableName = "orders";
            ordersBuilder.DataColumns.Add("order_id");
            ordersBuilder.DataColumns.Add("order_date");

            // tombstone table
            ordersBuilder.TombstoneTableName = "orders_tombstone";
            ordersBuilder.TombstoneDataColumns.Add("order_id");
            ordersBuilder.TombstoneDataColumns.Add("order_date");

            // tracking\sync columns
            ordersBuilder.CreationTrackingColumn = @"create_timestamp";
            ordersBuilder.UpdateTrackingColumn = @"update_timestamp";
            ordersBuilder.DeletionTrackingColumn = @"update_timestamp";
            ordersBuilder.UpdateOriginatorIdColumn = @"update_originator_id";

            SyncAdapter ordersSyncAdapter = ordersBuilder.ToSyncAdapter();
            ((SqlParameter)ordersSyncAdapter.SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand.Parameters["@sync_last_received_anchor"]).DbType = DbType.Binary;
            ((SqlParameter)ordersSyncAdapter.SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand.Parameters["@sync_new_received_anchor"]).DbType = DbType.Binary;
            serverSyncProvider.SyncAdapters.Add(ordersSyncAdapter);


            SqlSyncAdapterBuilder orderDetailsBuilder = new SqlSyncAdapterBuilder();
            orderDetailsBuilder.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.Bidirectional;
            orderDetailsBuilder.Connection = serverConnection;

            // base table
            orderDetailsBuilder.TableName = "order_details";
            orderDetailsBuilder.DataColumns.Add("order_id");
            orderDetailsBuilder.DataColumns.Add("order_details_id");
            orderDetailsBuilder.DataColumns.Add("product");
            orderDetailsBuilder.DataColumns.Add("quantity");

            // tombstone table
            orderDetailsBuilder.TombstoneTableName = "order_details_tombstone";
            orderDetailsBuilder.TombstoneDataColumns.Add("order_id");
            orderDetailsBuilder.TombstoneDataColumns.Add("order_details_id");
            orderDetailsBuilder.TombstoneDataColumns.Add("product");
            orderDetailsBuilder.TombstoneDataColumns.Add("quantity");

            // tracking\sync columns
            orderDetailsBuilder.CreationTrackingColumn = @"create_timestamp";
            orderDetailsBuilder.UpdateTrackingColumn = @"update_timestamp";
            orderDetailsBuilder.DeletionTrackingColumn = @"update_timestamp";
            orderDetailsBuilder.UpdateOriginatorIdColumn = @"update_originator_id";


            SyncAdapter orderDetailsSyncAdapter = orderDetailsBuilder.ToSyncAdapter();
            ((SqlParameter)orderDetailsSyncAdapter.SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand.Parameters["@sync_last_received_anchor"]).DbType = DbType.Binary;
            ((SqlParameter)orderDetailsSyncAdapter.SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand.Parameters["@sync_new_received_anchor"]).DbType = DbType.Binary;
            serverSyncProvider.SyncAdapters.Add(orderDetailsSyncAdapter);


            //
            // 6. Setup provider wide commands
            // There are two commands on the provider itself and not on a table sync adapter:
            // SelectNewAnchorCommand: Returns the new high watermark for current sync, this value is
            // stored at the client and used the low watermark in the next sync
            // SelectClientIdCommand: Finds out the client ID on the server, this command helps
            // avoid downloading changes that the client had made before and applied to the server
            //
            //

            // select new anchor command
            SqlCommand anchorCmd = new SqlCommand();
            anchorCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            anchorCmd.CommandText = "Select @" + SyncSession.SyncNewReceivedAnchor + " = @@DBTS";  // for SQL Server 2005 SP2, use "min_active_rowversion() - 1"
            anchorCmd.Parameters.Add("@" + SyncSession.SyncNewReceivedAnchor, SqlDbType.Timestamp).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            serverSyncProvider.SelectNewAnchorCommand = anchorCmd;

            // client ID command (give the client id of 1)
            // in remote server scenario (middle tear), this command will reference a local client table for the ID               
            SqlCommand clientIdCmd = new SqlCommand();
            clientIdCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            clientIdCmd.CommandText = "SELECT @" + SyncSession.SyncOriginatorId + " = 1";
            clientIdCmd.Parameters.Add("@" + SyncSession.SyncOriginatorId, SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            serverSyncProvider.SelectClientIdCommand = clientIdCmd;
```

Now the problem is how to synchronize from server to client. I think changing  `clientSyncProvider` will help but there is nothing like `selectServerIdCommand`. So don't know how to proceed. I tried lots of searching but not able to fine appropriate ans.

Comment: if you're sync works client to server, then server to client should work as well. it's just a matter of changing the sync direction. likewise, any particular reason why you're using the older sync providers?

Comment: We are developing win form application with remote database. Fetching data over network is very time consuming there no data caching in application also, So to improve performance we are using this concept. Can you please help how we can change the direction.

Comment: your code above already shows how to set SyncDirection, so not sure what else you're missing